# Json String to Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am trying to pass a Json String into my Javascript code to build up a list of markers on a Google Map.

The map code works fine as I have tested it fine with a hard coded Json Object but now i need to retrieve that data from my Model using the code below.

```
<script>
var markers = "@Model.JsonLifeboatLocations";
...
</script>
```

I don't get any script errors and no markers display using the above

Any ideas where im going wrong?

**View Model Getter:**

```
    public string JsonLifeboatLocations 
    {
        get 
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(LifeboatLocations);   
        }
    }
```

**Reference: The JavaScript code to display the markers**

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i];
    new google.maps.LatLng(data.Lat, data.Lon);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.Name
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source for the rendered page? That should show you if the Json is being serialized correctly. My guess is that the quotes around `@Model.JsonLifeboatLocations` are causing the Razor engine to interpret it as a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
var markers = @Html.Raw(Model.JsonLifeboatLocations);
...
</script>
```